# MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit Dialog losing focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit and I have a Dialog that lost focus when I execute some threaded methods.

1. First, I show a message to the user (works well);
2. Then, it starts another dialog with a progress ring (works well);
3. At the end, if we have a error response from server, another dialog pops-out with the error message:
   [No focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6ymS.jpg)

The problem is: the "OK" button is disabled. And just receive focus when I click it once.

Here is a source code:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7dlCQ9y_LsDdm1mU2RNNzlXem8

And this is the XAML from MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExample"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="0" Width="88" Height="31" Click="button_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>

    </Grid>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

And the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using WpfExample.Dialogs;

namespace WpfExample
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Asks for confirmation
        BeforeRemoveItem();
    }

    private string RemoveItem()
    {
        /// In my project I'm calling a DELETE on a Rest Server 
        /// and if an error ocurred, we return the error message...

        // "Simulates" a delay from server..
        // PS: Without this, the "OK" dialog works fine.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

        // Fake result
        return "An error has ocurred in Server";

    }

    private async void BeforeRemoveItem()
    {
        var messageDialog = new DialogQuestion
        {
            Message = {Text = "Do you want remove this item?"}
        };

        var result = await DialogHost.Show(messageDialog, "RootDialog", OnSelectAnswer);

    }

    private void OnSelectAnswer(object sender, DialogClosingEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if ((bool)eventArgs.Parameter == false)
            return;

        // Abort current process...
        eventArgs.Cancel();

        // Creates a new dialog, to show the progress bar...
        DialogProgress progresso = new DialogProgress();
        eventArgs.Session.UpdateContent(progresso);

        // Then starts a task..
        var t = Task<string>.Run(() =>
        {
            // Calls a methdo from server...
            return RemoveItem();
        })
        .ContinueWith(resultFromServer =>
        {
            // Now, with the answer from server we can do extra things..

            // If there is no message, we just close the current Message
            if (resultFromServer.Result == string.Empty)
            {
                eventArgs.Session.Close(false);
            }
            else
            {
                // If there is an error message, we show a simple dialog (with just an "OK" button) and shows the error..
                eventArgs.Cancel();
                eventArgs.Session.UpdateContent(new DialogOk { Message = { Text = resultFromServer.Result } });

            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() );
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: ...yeah current issue, awaiting a fix.